# Error thrown on navigator push : “!_debugLocked': is not true.”

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

When I tried to push from the initstate , this error shows up. Help

Import files here

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:corona_app/screens/home.dart';
```

Loading Screen Stateful Widget

```
class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  @override
```

initState

```
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Home()));

  }
  @override
```

Widget build

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SpinKitPouringHourglass(
          color: Colors.green,
          size: 100,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you try to replace your Navigator.push in your initState for this?

    
`Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
    });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Alpha Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9353496/alpha-bot) Try this code:

```
@override
void initState() {
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _afterLayout(context));
  super.initState();
}
```

Then create this method and navigate to your Home:

```
_afterLayout(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO
 Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Home()));
}
```